# All participants performed 12 binomial trials for the manipulation and control conditions. What is the best statistical test to compare conditions?

Tags: logistic, t-test, binomial-distribution, proportion, mcnemar-test

All 80 participants performed 12 binomial trials (0-failed, 1-success) for the manipulation condition and 12 binomial trials for the control condition.

My database is something like this, but with more rows and columns:

```
Subject  control_trial1  control_trial2 ... manipulation_trial1  manipulation_trial2 ...
      1               0               1                       1                    0
      2               1               0                       1                    1
      3               1               1                       1                    1
```

What is the best statistical test to see if the participants had more successes in the manipulation condition than in the control condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simulating The Data

There are a couple ways to do this.  To demonstrate, I'll first simulate some data in R

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(0)
d<-crossing(id=1:80,
         trial=1:12,
         condition = c('control','manipulation'))


X <- model.matrix(~condition, data = d)
Z <- model.matrix(~factor(id), data = d)
gamma <- rnorm(ncol(Z), 0, 0.2)
eta <- X %*% c(-0.8, 0.2) + Z %*% gamma
p <- plogis(eta)
y <- rbinom(nrow(d), 1, p)

d$y <- y
```

Note that the true outcome prevalence for control is about 31% and the outcome in the manipulation group is 35%. My recommendation  would be to manipulate the data to be in tidy format, as shown below.

```
# A tibble: 1,920 × 4
      id trial condition        y
   <int> <int> <chr>        <int>
 1     1     1 control          0
 2     1     1 manipulation     0
 3     1     2 control          1
 4     1     2 manipulation     0
 5     1     3 control          1
 6     1     3 manipulation     1
 7     1     4 control          0
 8     1     4 manipulation     0
 9     1     5 control          0
10     1     5 manipulation     1
```

Now, onto approaches for these data.

### Linear Regression

Assuming the marginal outcome rate is not too high or low, a linear regression could work fairly well.

```
lm(y ~ condition, data=d)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ condition, data = d)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.4156 -0.4156 -0.3583  0.5844  0.6417 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)            0.35833    0.01570   22.82  < 2e-16 ***
conditionmanipulation  0.05729    0.02220    2.58  0.00995 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4865 on 1918 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.003459,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.00294 
F-statistic: 6.658 on 1 and 1918 DF,  p-value: 0.009947
```

The estimates are fairly close to the actual data, and if we repeat the simulation many times, we see the estimates are unbiased for the true probabilities

[image]

This approach breaks down when the outcome probabilities are near 0 or 1, in which case you can use...

### Logistic Regression

Standard approach for these kinds of data.  Because all subjects have the same amount of observations, logistic regression should be more than enough to estimate the effects.

```r
glm(y~condition, data = d, family = binomial()) %>%
summary()

Call:
glm(formula = y ~ condition, family = binomial(), data = d)

Deviance Residuals: 
   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max  
-1.037  -1.037  -0.942   1.325   1.433  

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -0.58261    0.06731  -8.656   <2e-16 ***
conditionmanipulation  0.24185    0.09391   2.575     0.01 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 2562.7  on 1919  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 2556.1  on 1918  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2560.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

Note that the effects are now on the log odds scale so you have to do some more work to get those into a more interpretable scale.  Lastly, you could do...

### Mixed Effects Logistic Regression

This will allow you to estimate each subject's outcome prevalence and then estimate the between subject variability.  You can do this with

```
library(lme4)
glmer(y~condition + (1|id), data = d, family=binomial()) %>% 
  summary()

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace
  Approximation) [glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: y ~ condition + (1 | id)
   Data: d

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  2562.1   2578.8  -1278.0   2556.1     1917 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.8433 -0.8433 -0.7473  1.1858  1.3382 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 id     (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 1920, groups:  id, 80

Fixed effects:
                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)           -0.58261    0.06731  -8.656   <2e-16 ***
conditionmanipulation  0.24185    0.09391   2.575     0.01 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr)
cndtnmnpltn -0.717
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
boundary (singular) fit: see help('isSingular')
```

However, if you aren't interested in between subject variability, I would avoid this approach.

### My Recommendation

Depending on if you've ever worked with generalized linear models or not, I would first recommend logistic regression then followed by linear regression in the case the outcome is not very rare or very prevalent.